# I can't connect more than one sensor to the server in my java socket program

Tags: java, sockets

I Have implemented a server and client using sockets. In that multiple clients must able to connected.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Set;

import sensors.FireAlarmSensor;

public class SensorServer {
    private static final int port = 9000;
    private static HashMap<String, PrintWriter> fireSensorPrintersList = new HashMap<String, PrintWriter>();
    private static HashMap<String,FireAlarmSensor> fireSensorsList = new HashMap<String,FireAlarmSensor>();

    private static String sensorIDNumber;
    private static double temperatureLevel;
    private static double CO2Level;
    private static double batteryLevel;
    private static double smokeLevel;

    public static void main(String args[]){
        System.out.println("Sensor Server Is Running");
        ServerSocket clientListener = null;
        try {
            clientListener = new ServerSocket(port);
            new sensorHandler(clientListener.accept()).start();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally {
            try {
                clientListener.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }   
    }

    public static class sensorHandler extends Thread{
        private String sensorID;
        private Socket socket;
        private BufferedReader receiver;
        private PrintWriter sender;

        public sensorHandler(Socket socket) {
            this.socket = socket;
            try {
                this.receiver = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
                this.sender = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(),true);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void run(){
            while(true){
                sender.println("REQUESTID");
                try {
                    sensorID = receiver.readLine();             
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                if(sensorID == null){
                    System.out.println("Empty Sensor ID");
                }

                synchronized (fireSensorPrintersList) {
                    if(!fireSensorPrintersList.containsKey(sensorID)){
                        fireSensorPrintersList.put(sensorID,sender);
                        break;
                    }   
                }               
            }

            sender.println("SENSORACCEPTED");
            try{
                while(true){
                    //Set<String> sensorIDList= fireSensorPrintersList.keySet();
                    /*for(PrintWriter writer:fireSensorPrintersList.values()){
                        sensorIDNumber = fireSensorsList.get(sensorIDList).getSensorID();
                        temperatureLevel = fireSensorsList.get(sensorIDList).getTemperatureLevel();
                        batteryLevel = fireSensorsList.get(sensorIDList).getBatteryLevel();
                        CO2Level = fireSensorsList.get(sensorIDList).getCO2Level();
                        smokeLevel = fireSensorsList.get(sensorIDList).getSmokeLevel();
                    }*/

                    /*try {
                        Thread.sleep(3000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }*/
                }   
            }
            finally {
                try {
                    socket.close();
                    System.out.println("Sensor server closed");
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the code of client(Sensor).

```
package sensors;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class FireAlarmSensor implements Serializable{
    BufferedReader lineIn;
    PrintWriter lineOut;

    private String sensorID = "Not Set";
    private BatterySensor batterySensor;
    private TemperatureSensor temperatureSensor;
    private SmokeSensor smokeSensor;
    private CO2Sensor co2Sensor;

    public FireAlarmSensor(String sensorID){
        this.sensorID = sensorID;
        this.batterySensor = new BatterySensor();   
        this.temperatureSensor = new TemperatureSensor();
        this.smokeSensor = new SmokeSensor();
        this.co2Sensor = new CO2Sensor();
    }

    public FireAlarmSensor(){
        /*JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setSize(500, 500);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);*/
    }

    public String getSensorID(){
        return this.sensorID;
    }

    public double getBatteryLevel(){
        return batterySensor.getSensorData();
    }

    public double getTemperatureLevel(){
        return temperatureSensor.getSensorData();
    }

    public double getSmokeLevel(){
        return smokeSensor.getSensorData();
    }

    public double getCO2Level(){
        return co2Sensor.getSensorData();
    }

    public void run(){
        String serverAddress = "localhost";
        Socket socket = null;

        try {
            socket = new Socket(serverAddress,9000);
            lineIn = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
            lineOut = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(),true);

            while(true){
                String serverInput = lineIn.readLine();
                if(serverInput.startsWith("REQUESTID")){
                    Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
                    System.out.print("Enter the Sensor ID : ");
                    String sensorID = userInput.nextLine();
                    lineOut.println(sensorID);
                }
                else if(serverInput.startsWith("SENSORACCEPTED")){
                    System.out.println("Sensor Is Accepted");
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        /*finally{
            try {
                socket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }*/
    }

    public static void main(String args[]){
        FireAlarmSensor sensor = new FireAlarmSensor();
        sensor.run();
    }
}
```

Server is working perfectly fine in my program. It doesn't crash anytime and first sensor also can connected with the server and it also never get crashed. But when try to connect another sensor to a server by running the FireAlarmSensor.class file, 2nd sensor gives me following exception and crash.

```
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.Socket.<init>(Unknown Source)
at java.net.Socket.<init>(Unknown Source)
at sensors.FireAlarmSensor.run(FireAlarmSensor.java:64)
at sensors.FireAlarmSensor.main(FireAlarmSensor.java:96)
```

I'm running server and all the sensors in same machine using eclipse neon.

**Lines from 16 to 27 in Client(Sensor) cause an errors because I haven't uploaded that java files.Please comment or delete them when you running it.**

Comment: You only ever call `accept()` once.

Comment: I'm a newby in java socket programming. Can you explain it littlebit more ?

Comment: Thanks cubrr. Now it works fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `main` method only calls `accept` once, so it is not surprising that only one client can connect. Try accepting clients in a loop:

```
private static boolean shouldExit = false;

public static void main(String args[]) {
    System.out.println("Sensor Server Is Running");

    try (ServerSocket listener = new ServerSocket(port)) {
        acceptLoop(listener);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private static void acceptLoop(ServerSocket listener) throws IOException {
    while (!shouldExit) {
        // accept() blocks until a connection is made
        Socket client = listener.accept();
        new sensorHandler(client).start();
    }
}
```

What this will do is just loop forever, accepting new clients until you set `shouldExit` to be `true`. The main thread, that is.

I've taken the liberty to make use of the Java 7 [`try`-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) statement (`try (ServerSocket listener = ...)`). It does essentially what your convoluted try-catch-finally did - automatically closes the ServerSocket.